# download_this issue within a 'for' loop

Tags: for-loop, download, this

I'm successfully using download_this to prompt users to download individual data files and plots in an Rmarkdown-with-parameters.  The problem is when requesting a download button using 'download_this' in a for-loop (see below). The behavior is that it appears to do a download (see log) without creating a button (as it might using ggsave), but i can't find the plots on disk.  I have tried adding plot.new() and got some kind of syntax error (maybe because it was chained in dplyr?). I don't think lapply would work as its a loop also. Updated all packages. Rstudio 2022.12.0 Build 353, [64-bit] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2.

Code:

```
       # Map individual variables ES
       value.maps <- list()
       vars <- levels(plot.sf$variable); 
       nvars <- length(vars)
       for (ii in 1:nvars) 
       {
                this.var <- vars[[ii]] 
                this.sf <- plot.sf %>% 
                    filter(variable==this.var) %>%
                    select(-c('fips.huc8', 'variable'))
                 
                print(paste0('Creating map for ', this.var))
                
                fill.name = bquote(.(this.var)~value~"("*Mg^{-1}*")")
                map <- maps.fips.huc(this.sf, fill.name=fill.name, nq=nq, digits=digits, my.pal='YlGnBu', states.sf=MA.states.sf) 
                 
            value.maps[[ii]] <- map + theme_grey(20) +  
             theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'), 
                   axis.text = element_text(size=11),
                   legend.position=c(0.20, 0.85), 
                   legend.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'), 
                   legend.box.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA),     
                   legend.title=element_text(size=12),
                   legend.text=element_text(size=10), 
                   legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,0)
       #              legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.5, "cm")
                )
            
            # Plot maps to html output
          print(value.maps[[ii]])
          
          # Save plots to separate files
          if (params$save.plots) {
               value.maps[[ii]] %>%
                download_this(
                     output_name = paste0('map.', this.var),
                     output_extension = ".png",
                     button_label = paste0("Download ", this.var, " map"),
                     button_type = "default",
                     has_icon = TRUE, 
                     icon = "fa fa-save"
                ) 
                print(paste0('Map.', this.var, '.png saved?' ))
          }
       }
```

The screenshot of the html output generated shows examples of successful download_this buttons for data followed by a gratuitous download without a button from within the loop and [part of] a map plotted in the html output (but not as separate .png files).